# Execute a Managed bean from a JSF view in WEB-INF folder

Tags: spring, jsf

We are initiating a Spring + Primefaces project and the first problem we have encountered concerns storing the XHTML pages into the WEB-INF folder.

When we use a faces form in a view located inside the WEB-INF folder, then the `commandButton` does not execute the managed bean method.

```
 <h:form id="loginForm">
    <p:commandButton action="#{LoginMgr.doLogin()}" value="Login"/>
 </h:form>
```

Our bean:

```
<bean id="LoginMgr" name="LoginMgr" class="com.tesipro.channelmanager.business.implemented.CMLoginManager">
</bean>
```

In fact we think the problem is that with JSF, the pages are rendered using a link to the same page as the action of the form, so if the page is located in WEB-INF it is not publicly accessible.

We know that having all our XHTML views in the web folder instead of WEB-INF actually solves the issue, but we would like to store that pages into WEB-INF.

Comment: Since this question is too old to me migrated, I suggest deleting it and posting it over on StackOverflow. I guess you will get an expedite answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does storing it in "app/WEB-INF/view" folder help? We do have several actions defined in XHTMLs in "app/WEB-INF/view" folder. Not invoking a spring bean from there, though, but calling a web-flow action.